# Steganography software

Tags: linux, security, cryptography, steganography

Do you know some good (better if FOSS and cross-platform) steganography software that runs on GNU/Linux?

The features I'm searching are:

- steganography software (better if FOSS and cross-platform)
- it must run on GNU/Linux
- must hide data inside audio/video/image files
- support of additional cryptography

I already use a cryptographic software, but I want to use a steganographic one as an addition to it.

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know of a one-size-fits-all application that can perform these operations on audio,video, and image files, but the [StegoArchive](http://home.comcast.net/~ebm.md/stego.html) website contains a massive archive of steganography software, if you don't mind using multiple tools for the job. You can even order a CD containing the software on the website!

For cross-platform, check out their [Java section](http://home.comcast.net/~ebm.md/stego/softwarejava.html). For GNU/Linux, check out their [Unix/FreeBSD/Linux section](http://home.comcast.net/~ebm.md/stego/softwareunix.html).

A lot of it is freeware, and open source, so you probably won't need to put any money down to get this job done.

Comment: most CLI steg software written in C/C++ can probably be recompiled under Cygwin with no modifications; even some of the GUIs may work on Windows with Cygwin or Ming X-windows.

Comment: @~quack +1 excellent point.

Comment: WOW! This StegoArchive link explain your 38.8K points of reputation! Thanks! (And this is candidate to be the winner of the bounty...I'm just waiting some other neat suggestion!) :D

Comment: @John T Is [this](http://members.cox.net/ebmmd/stego/stego.html) the new site for StegoArchive?

Comment: @AndrejaKo I think it is. Looks like the author switched ISPs.

Comment: The link to StegoArchive isn't working...

Answer (score 5):

[Steghide](http://steghide.sourceforge.net) is available as an Ubuntu package

Comment: Hi lain, and thanks! I know steghide, but it lacks the feature of hide data inside video formats...or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

here's a quite intriguing project:

**[Hydan](http://www.crazyboy.com/hydan/)** can embed messages into an executable without altering its size.

Hydan steganographically conceals a message into an application. It exploits redundancy in the i386 instruction set by defining sets of functionally equivalent instructions.

It then encodes information in machine code by using the appropriate instructions from each set.

Features:

- Application filesize remains unchanged
- Message is blowfish encrypted with a user-supplied passphrase before being embedded
- Encoding rate: 1/110

Hydan is crossplatform (BSD/Linux/Windows) FOSS.

Comment: This is a very nice piece of software, although it hasn't the feature I was searching: I'll add it to my list, though! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

**SilentEye** is a cross-platform (Windows/Mac/Linux) application design for an easy use of steganography

http://www.silenteye.org/

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of Steg, a portable cross-platform software for steganography,
written in C++, available here:

http://www.fabionet.org

For now there is support for images only (jpg and uncompressed).
The other requirements you are searching for are all meet.
Is not FOSS but really, does not contain any surprise if not some nice parameter you can tune for your steganography intent. ;-)