# How do I hide files inside of an image without using any stenganography tools

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, security, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Steganography software](https://superuser.com/questions/95877/steganography-software)

I want to hide files inside of a picture. The files may be music or video. Is it technically possible to do this? If so, how?

I searched on Google to find methods,suggest ***some methods for beginners*** ,i don't know where to start from,so guide me

Important note : Modifying the size of an image up to certain extent
e.g
before hiding image size : 1mb
after hiding image size can be up to 4mb.

i referred following url's:

```
martinolivier.com/open/stegoverview.pdf
www.garykessler.net/library/steganography.html
www.jjtc.com/ihws98/jjgmu.html
pcplus.techradar.com/.../secrets-of-steganography/ - United Kingdom
```

these are some examples sir

please note the answers were marked for ***hiding data inside image with software***

Comment: The thought may be crazy since lot of encryption programs available,i wish to try something new,

Comment: Try refining your search with the term [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)

Comment: You cannot do this without changing the image data in some way, if you want to embed data in the image and retain the same size then you will have to reduce the image quality.  Your note of "without modifying the size of an image" is an impossible requirement and as such I am voting to close.

Comment: without modifying certain extent

Comment: Fair enough, that seems more reasonable.  Have you already found some tools that do the job?  Steganography tools as suggested by Mike do exist, have you tried any and found them lacking in features?  [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/230915/geek-to-live--hide-data-in-files-with-easy-steganography-tools) has a neat guide on tools that do this.

Comment: @-  ping mokubai "sir i found some tools but all explaining about merging files" e.g http://www.howtogeek.com/119365/how-to-hide-zip-files-inside-a-picture-without-any-extra-software/

Comment: Vignesh, you shouldn't write `@- ping mokubai`, but `@Mokubai`. Please click the "help" button to see another example. In general, just write @username.

Comment: @Mokubai please review my question sir

Comment: @sathya please review my question sir

Comment: @Journeyman Geek please review my question sir

Comment: The answer is that **you don’t**. You can easily append a file to a picutre without any special tools, but if you want to hide it as well, then you *must* use special programs.

Comment: @Synetech i edited question sir please review it

Comment: @Synetech i dont know where to begin from please guide me

Comment: I told you, if you want to really hide it, then you need stego software because Windows does not come with anything that can do what you want. What do you want or *need* to do?

Comment: Let me get this right.  You want to do steganography without using steganography tools?  I am kind of getting the idea that we are either misunderstanding what you are trying to do or you do not understand the limitations of computer software.   If you are wanting you can hide a file "behind" a file using [Alternate Data Streams](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/alternate_data_streams.html) on Windows computers. Please could you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried because at the moment what you are asking for is sounding kind of impossible.

Comment: @Mokubai sir i Try to achieve Manually the work done by software Like Stegomagic,as you mentioned its impossible I mentioned the Articles i refereed to do it, i agree with your link "Alternate data stream link"  but if you have time please read this PDF sir martinolivier.com/open/stegoverview.pdf i found it possible

Comment: Steganography is completely possible, but you've reworded your title to exclude using those kinds of tools.  Are you now wanting to learn how to do it yourself (in which case teaching you is outside the remit of this site) or are you wanting to do something completely different?  If you want to discuss this rather than bash a comment thread and work out how or if we can help you I suggest checking out our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [StegoMagic](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=stegomagic%20download&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFYQFjAA&url=http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Encrypting/StegoMagic.shtml&ei=u1wSUL6oE8forQeA34DABQ&usg=AFQjCNG3Fueq7DK0NFGFpw0nTRlUUxEIow)! This software can be used to hide text files inside image file, and you can also hide any file into any file. By the way in the field of encryption software, I like Truecrypt the most, it's free and powerful. I recommend you to try it. I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 5):

Hiding data inside inside an image is done by using [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography), this method can be used to hide data inside other files types too for example mp3 and video to name a few.

I can't recommend any particular software but a quick web search finds this free windows tool [QuickStego](http://quickcrypto.com/free-steganography-software.html). It shouldn't be hard for you to find more if this doesn't fit your needs.

Be aware of it's limitations though.
Steganography just hides the data and unless you also encrypt it it can be extracted by tools such as [Stegdetect](http://www.outguess.org/detection.php/).

You can read more about steganography and ask questions about it over on [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  But I don't really get why you would go through such trouble as there are really good encryption programs out there.

[How to Hide Zip Files Inside a Picture Without any Extra Software](http://www.howtogeek.com/119365/how-to-hide-zip-files-inside-a-picture-without-any-extra-software/)

The process involves using the command prompt and adding the files together with the /B switch

```
copy /B picture.gif+YourMenu.zip newfile.gif
```

Comment: i like to mention that post was related to merging and it doesn't mean to hide,

Comment: The command just merges the folders into the picture,i guess merging is different from hiding.

Comment: @wbeard52 I have seen this method once, and i have use it before. But Main Problem is i don't know how to unbind the file. Could u help me?

Comment: The point of encryption is to conceal the content of a message. The point of stenography is to conceal the *existence* of a message. One won't do when you need the other.

Comment: @Titan Zach  Try WinRAR to view the contents of the two files.

Comment: @wbeard52 Thanks for your information.

Comment: @vignesh, so you want to inject a file *and* hide it, but *not* use specialized stego tools? `o.O` You can’t do that.

Comment: There are several methods to hide data inside an image sir ,i have refereed following urls: